# Angular Error: $injector:unpr Unknown Provider

Tags: angularjs

I am getting the followin error

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: AuthProvider <- Auth <- LoginCtrl
```

and my code looks like the following...

```
'use strict';

angular.module('yapp')
  .controller('LoginCtrl', function($scope, $location,Auth,$log) {

    $scope.submit = function(email,password) {

        var model = {
            email:'',
            password:''
        };

        $scope.model = model;

          Auth.login(email,password)
              .then(function(token){
                    $log.info(token);
              },function (error){
                    $log.info(error);
          });
    }

  });
```

'use strict';

angular.module('yapp')
  .factory('Auth', function($http,$q,$log,APIHelper) {

```
var self = this;

  this.login = function(email,password){
      var d = $q.defer();
      var requestUrl = APIHelper.endpoints.login;
      var data = {
          email:email,
          password:password
      };
      $http({
          url:requestUrl,
          dataType: 'json',
          method: 'POST',
          data:data,
          headers: {
              "Content-Type": "application/json"
          }
      })
          .success(function(data,status,headers,config){
              d.resolve(data);
          })
          .error(function(data,status,headers,config){
              d.reject(data);
          });
      return d.promise;
  }

return self;
```

});

Answer (score 1):

This usually happens when you haven't included the file in which you have defined the service. Are you sure you did a script import or a module.export for that?